# Sort array based on numeric value on second line of each element

Tags: php, sorting, numeric

I write an array like this:

```
$tags = [
    "Channel1\n" . 26210,
    "Channel2\n" . 7896 . "\n---------------",
    "Channel3\n" . 5035 . "\n---------------",
    "Channel4\n" . 25794 . "\n---------------",
    "Channel5\n" . 91143 . "\n---------------",
    "Channel6\n" . 42075 . "\n---------------",
    "Channel7\n" . 11815 . "\n---------------",
    "Channel8\n" . 180 . "\n---------------",
    "Channel9\n" . 171 . "\n---------------",
    "Channel10\n" . 82106  . "\n---------------"
];
```

Now I use `sort()` function to sort this array, But I need it sorted only by those integers that display between two strings (specific part of an array). For example: `Channel9 - 171 , Channel8 - 180 ...`

Comment: You need to state how you get the array, do you define it like that or get it from somewhere?  Also, show what output you want to get.

Comment: So what is your problem? You can't sort? You can't show? You can't what?

Comment: @AbraCadaver i wanna get the correct order of those integer with own concatenates. for example : Channel9 - 171 | Channel8 - 180 and ...

Comment: You should be use `uasort()` to define sort rules by yourself.

Comment: @CalosKao please give me an example, im new to PHP

Comment: There are examples here http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably get the numbers in an array and sort on that:

```
$nums = preg_filter('/[^\n][^\d]+/', '', $tags); //or preg_replace()
array_multisort($nums, $tags);
```

A slightly longer approach:

```
usort($tags, function($a, $b) {
                 $a = explode("\n", $a)[1];
                 $b = explode("\n", $b)[1];
                 if ($a == $b) { return 0; }
                 return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `preg_filter()` offers no advantage over `preg_replace()`. `preg_filter()` (in fringe cases not represented in the asker's sample data) can mutate the size of the array which would lead to code breakage when implemented with `array_multisort()` because the sorting atray's size must be the same as the input array.
2. `/[^\n][^\d]+/` [actually damages all elements except the first element](https://3v4l.org/0a8bE).

Instead, I recommend preparing the sorting array with `preg_replace()` and a whole-string pattern with a capture group.

The generated array of numeric strings will be treated as integers by default in the `array_multisort()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iSf4O))

```
array_multisort(
    preg_replace(
        "/\S+\n(\d+).*/s",
        '$1',
        $tags
    ),
    $tags
);
var_export($tags);
```

The regex pattern matches non-whitespace characters, then a newline, then captures the full integer value, then greedily matches the rest of the string.  The captured numeric string is then used to replace the whole input string.  The same behavior is applied to all elements in the array.

---

Using `usort()` is less attractive because it would require two function calls per iteration. In other words, just use `array_multisort()` for best efficiency / fewer function calls.

Below `sscanf()` is used to parse the predictably formatted string.  `%*[^\n]` will match (but not return) the leading substring upto the first `\n`, then match and return the second numeric substring as an int-type value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JmHCf))

```
usort(
    $tags,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        sscanf($a, "%*[^\n]%d")
        <=>
        sscanf($b, "%*[^\n]%d")
);
var_export($tags);
```

---

Or trim all characters prior to the first occurring newline, then cast that string to an integer to remove the unwanted characters. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5mLBV))

```
usort(
    $tags,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        (int) strpbrk($a, "\n")
        <=>
        (int) strpbrk($b, "\n")
);
var_export($tags);
```